# Pointer to data in array. Delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to compare two Byte arrays. 
`byInputBuffer` is an array which I filled by external device. 256 bytes comes in every main loop iteration and is always put in the beginning of `byInputBuffer`. It is declared like here:

```
byInputBuffer: array [0..1023] of byte;
```

`DataArray` is an array with dynamically declared size. So array is declared like here:

```
DataArray  : Array of Byte;
```

and then in code size is declared like here:

```
 SetLength(DataArray, DataLengthInt);
```

where DataLengthInt is 130952.

Main loop is iterated from 0 to 511, but when i=0 I get BoolToStr(verify)=-1 in code presented below:

```
leftBytes := 256;

verify := CompareMem(@byInputBuffer, @DataArray[(i*256)], leftBytes);
```

But I checked and contents of both arrays when i=0 is equal for the first 256 elements.

My question is why CompareMem returns -1?

Other used declarations:

```
  leftBytes : Integer;
  verify : Boolean;
```

Comment: Please show more code, and try to format it better.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Get rid of all irrelevant parts (memo2 etc.), and specify what the data is **exactly**, and **exactly** what you want to do.

Comment: show variables declarations and full datatypes. `byInputBuffer, DataArray` - what are they ? Full declaration including all used datatypes is *required* to guess at real binary data layout.

Comment: Have you tried to use `CompareMem(@byInputBuffer[0], @DataArray[(i*256)], leftBytes);` ?

Comment: @TLama He shouldn't have to for static array.

Comment: @TLama: No need. Static arrays are stored 'in place' in memory.

Comment: `CompareMem` doesn't return `-1`. It returns either true or false. Neither of which has ordinal value of `-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `CompareMem` to compare the first 256 bytes of `byInputBuffer` against the first 256 bytes of `DataArray`.

You are then taking the return value of `CompareMem` and passing it through `BoolToStr`. That maps `False` to `'0'` and `True` to `'-1'`.

The conclusion therefore is that the first 256 bytes of the two arrays are equal. Because `CompareMem` returned `True`.

Note that your statement in the question that `CompareMem` returned `-1` is obviously incorrect. That is a big part of our confusion. Precision and accuracy are crucial when programming.

Comment: The OP should use `BoolToStr(..., true)` to get less confused in the future.

Comment: I thought that CompareMem returns 0 if equal.

Comment: It never returns `0`. It returns a `Boolean`. A value of `True` means the buffers are equal, a value of `False` means that they differ. When unsure, consult the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.CompareMem).

Comment: Ok, thank you all very much for your patience. I hope I will ask in better way in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why CompareMem returns -1?
>
> Other used declarations:

```
leftBytes : Integer;
verify : Boolean;
```

That is strange, because a boolean is `True` or `False`, and not numeric. How do you get that -1 value?

When in need, `False` is always translated/converted to zero. Every other value is not false, thus true.

So, I suspect you misinterpret your debugging, and the result of CompareMem being just fine.

Comment: No. `Boolean = (False, True)` and so `1` is the ordinal value for `True`.

Comment: This is now a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I get -1 when I do `Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(BoolToStr(verify));`

Comment: @bLAZY That is a crucial detail. Don't hide it away in a comment. Put it in the question!